# Keeping logged in user information

Tags: vue.js, laravel-passport

I managed to log in with laravel passport. I have the token, great. But I want to keep logged in user information, name, avatar and so on.

My login procedure gets oauth token. In dashboard component I make api call for user data.

Should I keep them in global Vue object or use Vuex? Is it safe?

Comment: Can you give more information on how you are using vue? Are you building a one page application which never reloads using the router?

Comment: I'm making single page app and I'm using vue-router.

Comment: You could hold the user information in your root vue instance then and propagate it to all other components using the router-view. Another option is to declare a wrapping vue component (usually inline component -> without template) to hold this information. You can also bind the required data to the window directly or put it in the local storage or as cookie data.

Comment: Many possibilites. So, there are no safety considerations? Should I autoclear them?

Comment: It highly depends on how you want to access this information (and where you want to do that). My suggestion would probably to store the token itself as cookie - so that you don't need to handle it anywhere else but in your http client interceptor (axios?) and store the userdata in a wrapping vue component. This will allow you to propagate all the information to all other components.

Comment: Join your comments and paste them as answer. I accept your answer, it cleared my newToVue doubts. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some options you might consider

- store data in cookies
- use localStorage
- keep everything in the root vue instance
- keep everything in a wrapping vue component

My suggestion would be to store the auth token - that is actually required to successfully call your backend - in a cookie. This will make it super easy to access it with each and every request you send.

To store the user information I'd suggest to either create a wrapping component or use the root vue instance. The following example should clearify this.

**wrapping home component (inline template)**

```
data: function() {
  return { userinfo: {} }
},

created: function() {
  // load your user info
}
```

Then use it in your index.html / main view

```
<body>
  <home inline-template>
    <!-- any stuff here -->

    <!-- pass the user prop to every component that is shown in the userinfo -->
    <router-view :user="userinfo"></router-view>
  </home>
</body>
```

Your components that are shown in the router-view can then access the user prop

**example component**

```
...

props: ['user'],

...

<template>
   <span>{{ user.name }}</span>
</template>

...
```

IMPORTANT: to make this work you will also need to add **props: true** to the definition of your route. Everything is explained here in detail: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/passing-props.html

Remark: If you don't want to load userdata in your wrapping component you can load it anywhere else and use an event bus to transfer the results to the wrapping component. However, you should always have only ONE source of truth regarding the user info. Store it only at a single place.

Answer (score 1):

I found the session helper really easy to use and it solved the problem of globally using the oauth token:

See: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/session, heading: The Global Session Helper