# How to give access to page in Vue.js only if a user is logged in / localStorage exists?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I currently have a simple Vue.js application, I am using vue-router like this. `index.html`

```
<p>
  <router-link to="/" exact> Home </router-link>
  <router-link to="/about"> About </router-link>
  <router-link to="/contact"> Contact </router-link>
  <router-link to="/login"> Login </router-link>
  <router-link to="/register"> Register </router-link>
</p>
<router-view></router-view>
```

And I have this in my `/routes.js`

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

let routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: require('./components/Home.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    component: require('./components/About.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/login',
    component: require('./components/Login.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/register',
    component: require('./components/Register.vue')
  }
];

export default new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
});
```

I have `index.js` file which initialized the app, I think I should do something within my `created(){}` module but I am not sure how it is done.

I can set/unset sessions, all I need to know is how to give access to a page only if this session exists.

Comment: The is a lot of information on this in the Vue.js forums.  This might be of use for others with the same question: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-set-up-a-global-middleware-or-a-route-guard-to-vue-router-js-help/7893

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/navigation-guards.html) to verify some data before transition of page conclude.

---

It depends. With Navigation Guards you can verify if a user is logged before a transition of pages. Eg:

If user is on `/home` and he wants go to `/dashboard`, before user enter on `/dashboard`, a Navigation Guard will verify if user is logged. If yes, continue to `/dashboard`, if not, redirect to `/login`.

Internally, you can set a data of user when he do the login. Has many ways to do this thing but you must consider the security of system, etc.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43469358/keeping-logged-in-user-information) has a simple example to verify a user logged and [this article](https://medium.com/front-end-hacking/persisting-user-authentication-with-vuex-in-vue-b1514d5d3278) shows how to do this verification using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/), being more intesting.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit? How would I show navbars for example only if user is logged in